# Is it possible to create an automatic template for pull requests in Github?

Tags: github

I want to create a template that will appear automatically on each pull request.

This can either be a note or a comment. Ideally it will display guidelines as to reviewing the pull request:

```
- [ ] Have you done x?
- [ ] Have you done y?
- [ ] Have you done z?
```

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: See also "[Multiple issue and pull request templates"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481402/6309)", since January 2018.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible.

Add a file named `pull_request_template.md` to the root of your project:

```
- [ ] Have you done x?
- [ ] Have you done y?
- [ ] Have you done z?
```

You can also create a template for issues using the same convention. Just name the file `issue_template.md`.

Source: https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates

Comment: It appears that the template has to be in the project's default branch in order to be used. Eg, suppose the default branch is `master`, but you want to do a PR from `some_feature` to `beta`. When you start the PR, the interface shows the PR going to `master`. If your template is in `master`, it will be used, but if it's in `beta`, it won't be used, even after you change the selection for the PR base.

Comment: The template can also go into the `.github/` folder, to avoid clutter at the root level

Answer (score 4):

<del>GitHub does not allow you to create a template for pull requests created on it's website.</del>

The solution we use is to create pull requests using the github api via the `hub` command. We wrap this in a script called makePR that does something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$(hub pull-request -F PR-template.md)
echo "New PR created at $URL"
open $URL
```

(untested - our actual script does a lot more - I've left out parameters I think you don't need)

The `open` command will open the URL in the default browser on MacOS, you may need to adjust this for other platforms. Once it is open, you can edit the title in your web browser.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.

Comment: @ThomasW This simple version is obsolete, but the real version inserted more dynamic stuff into the PR description, depending on the name of the branch, including links to the issue on JIRA etc.

Comment: I should have said, the first sentence is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub now support pull request template through `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` file

[image: Pull request template sample]

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Unfortunately, this is not possible with GitHub alone.</strike> Good news, GitHub now supports this! Check out the accepted answer.

Also, GitHub has a pretty cool (and somewhat hidden) feature that you can use to link potential contributors to some contribution information whenever they create a new issue or pull request.

From [Contributing Guidelines](https://github.com/blog/1184-contributing-guidelines) on [The Github Blog](https://github.com/blog/):

> We've tried making this easy for everyone. As a maintainer, all you have to do is add a CONTRIBUTING file (or CONTRIBUTING.md if you're using Markdown) to the root of your repository. Then we will add a link to your file when a contributor creates an Issue or opens a Pull Request.
>
> [image: GitHub screenshot]
>
> Now, as soon as your collaborators start participating, they can easily find the guidelines you'd like them to follow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chrome extension that claims to do it here:
https://github.com/sprintly/pull-request-template-chrome-extension

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work, but the code looks simple enough to figure out and fix - I expect it's something simple that has broken due to github or chrome being updated.

It only seems to allow you to use a single template for every github pull request that you make, rather than pull in the correct template for the current repository.

Comment: The same author also published https://quickleft.com/blog/pull-request-template-bookmarklet/ Their system uses javascript urls to execute arbitrary code on your current page. Effectively pasting a hard coded values into your body.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is possible to create templates for issues and pull requests.  It can be described in the `ISSUE_TEMPLATE`, or `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` files in the repository root or in the `.github` folder.

You can find more information here https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates