# Is it possible to have/use multiple github issue templates on GitHub?

Tags: github

As the title say, is there a way to accomplish this?

Like having individual issue templates, one for bug reports `ISSUE_TEMPLATE_BUG.md`, one for general suggestions and proposals `ISSUE_TEMPLATE_PROPOSAL.md` etc and then choosing one of them when creating a new issue.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Like this page says: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue-template-for-your-repository/, you can only add the template to the default branch and other branches won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Albeit [@VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481402/5632158) is correct, GitHubs integration of issue templates has since improved, so I'll sum the current ways up:

### The easy (new) way

In the repository's main settings, click on the green button labelled **Start template setup** within the *Issues* feature element.
Then, just follow the instructions provided by GitHub to add, name and edit the issue templates.

These templates will then be added as Markdown files to the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` directory within your project root.

You then can decide whether to edit them directly in your IDE/text editor or directly within GitHub in the same way as stated above.

If you prefer the [official, pictured guide](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-issue-templates-for-your-repository/), feel free to use it. ;-)

### The manual (old) way

Like [@VonC explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481402/5632158), just add some markdown files to the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` directory. You can reference them by adding `?template=filename.md` to the new issue URL.

I'd recommend using a standard template (`.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md`) with a list of your available templates, like:

```
Please switch to **Preview** and select one of the following links:

* [Feature](?template=feature.md)
* [Bug](?template=bug.md)

Once switched to the correct template, you can save the link as a bookmark. Keep in mind that switching templates will remove all already entered data within this issue.
```

This allows to get the desired template with just two clicks instead of copy and paste.

### Comparison

The only difference between the files generated by the new method and the manual (old) ones is a small table at the top containing the name and description of each template.
You can transform your existing files easily by simply adding these lines at the top:

```
---
name: Bug report
about: Use this one for existing problems in the STN, which shouldn't be there.

---
```

I would prefer the new way as it's only a wrapper for the old way and you can still use all it's features, like bookmarks with `?template=filename.md` and editing via IDE and text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Since January (25th) 2018, 3 months after this OP (Oct. 2017), this is now possible.

See "[**Multiple issue and pull request templates**](https://github.com/blog/2495-multiple-issue-and-pull-request-templates)"

> **To add multiple issue templates to a repository create an `ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` directory in your project root**.
>   Within that `ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` directory you can create as many issue templates as you need, for example `ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bugs.md`.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7321362/35420642-8e5271e2-01f3-11e8-8109-0d21ddb89011.png]

> To use those issue templates add `?template=` and your template name to the new issue URL.
>   Continuing the example, if you create the template `bugs.md`, you add `?template=bugs.md` to the new issue URL, so it becomes `/issues/new?template=bugs.md`.

Comment: Hey there, is there a more automated way to do so? Lack of automation over editing the URL manually for Pull requests, makes it quite unhandy. Thanks

Comment: @JakubGawecki Not that I know of. The CLI [`gh issue create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_create), for instance, does not mention template